# Xcode - Change the status bar in a UIActivityViewController selected activity

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

How do I change the status bar in a UIActivityViewController selected activity as in Message or Mail.
I am able to change the bar tint color, the title color and the buttons tint colors. Just not the status bars color.
I saw this question was asked a few times already but they where quit old so I was wondering if someone found the answer.

Thanks